# Make LDAP search don't show DN

Tags: shell, ldap, sh, distinguishedname

How would I make a bourne shell code for a LDAP search to not return DN and return only CN? I am using iTerm2 for this.

Comment: I have tried using cn filter to show the cn, but I can't find anything about removing the DN return. I have tried --searchScope one, but it won't return anything.

Comment: You need to show what the LDAP output looks like.

Comment: dn: uid=zsarour,ou=august,ou=2013,ou=paris,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr

dn: uid=zcarde,ou=august,ou=2014,ou=paris,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr 
Something like this, only there are a lot more of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to see the `cn` results, then you can use something like:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -L <blah> cn | grep '^cn:'
```

> where `<blah>` is your bind/search conditions

the reason it returns the `dn` is because the returned data would not be properly formed ldif without it.

> By using `-o ldif-wrap=no` you don't have to cope with issues involving line-wrapping of the returned data.

Comment: Use the _exclude_ notation of grep, to exclude the dn, then the Right Side of the command stays constant and additional attributes can be added to the Left Side.  `ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -LLL <blah> mail | grep -v -E '(^$|dn:)'`